# boost::option_description get default value

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I need to get default value from `boost::program_options::option_description` class.

I checked source codes and looks like it stores default value both as `std::string` and as `boost::any`, but it is stored in private `m_default_as_text`, so I can't extract this information from there.

All I can get is formatted argument like that

> arg (=10)

but I want to get 10 only.

I also can get default value as `boost::any` by calling `value_semantic::apply_default` method

```
boost::any default_value;
opt_ptr->semantic()->apply_default(default_value)
```

but I don't know the exact type to do `boost::any_cast` when I'm iterating over the `option_description` collection, I just want to print it.

**update**

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description descr("options");

descr.add_options()
    ("help,h", "produce help message")
    ("a", po::value<int>()->default_value(42));

for (auto opt: descr.options())
{
    std::cout << opt->format_parameter() << std::endl;
}
```

here it prints

> arg (=42)

I want to get 42 as string without type knowledge.

Is there any way?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you add some more pseudo code to the question?

Comment: No ideas at all? As a workaround I'm parsing arg(=42) for now, but I would preffer something better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use (after calling store):

```
if(vm["a"].defaulted())
{
  //the value for a was set to the default value
  std::string a_1  = vm["a"].as<std::string>();

  //the other option is to get the int and lexical_cast it
  std::string a_2  = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(vm["a"].as<int>());
}
else
{
  //vm["a"] was not defaulted
  //So, why would you need to know the default value?
}
```

The other option (and the better way) is to use boost::lexical_cast to convert an int to a string (set the value to a **parameter** rather than a **magic number**):

```
constexpr int dv_a = 42;
//if (using C++11)

//const int dv_a = 42;
//if you are not using C++11

po::options_description descr("options");

descr.add_options()
("help,h", "produce help message")
("a", po::value<int>()->default_value(dv_a));

std::string string_dv_a = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(dv_a);
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer. The problem is that I don't know exact type of the `vm["a"]`, so calling `as<int>` may raise exception, because `a` can be anything.

Comment: It seems odd that you are complaining about that. You declare how the parameters are stored. Thus if you pass nothing (argc = 1, argv = program_name) to the variable map the argument will be defaulted; then just use: `vm["a"].as<std::string>()`;

Comment: I don't really get what you mean,maybe the question is not clearly described. I want to get default value as string without knowing the original type. It can be int, string, double or anything else, what I need is converting it to string. I can see from source codes that boost stores default value as string internally, but it is stored as a private variable and not exposed to the user. It's not me who declares parameters. I have only object of type `po::options_description` and I need to extract default values.

Comment: I guess what I mean, if you have a `po::options_description`; you should use the mechanics that are available in the other part of the library (parsing of commandline, storing values into a variable map) rather than breaking the current implementation. So, in this case:
`po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);`
Thus, values should be stored into the variable map properly (and you can check if its defaulted as I outlined above). Note call `as<std::string>()` on the variable_map to get what is stored as a string.